# Is there any way to do this without writing the file to memory first?

Tags: python, io, speech-recognition, moviepy, pytube

I have this code that transcibes the audio stream of some youtube video gived the `link`,
now as you might except this is quite slow since I must downlaod the video stream first as an `.mp4` then convert it, using `moviepy`, to `.wav` then record the audio then transcribe it.
I want to have the exact same functionality but without downloading the stream first by writing the data of the stream to some buffer for example.

```
from pytube import YouTube
import speech_recognition as sr
from moviepy.editor import *

video = YouTube(url=link)
audio_stream = video.streams.get_by_itag(140)

recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

audio_stream.download(filename="mp4_output.mp4")
audio = AudioFileClip("mp4_output.mp4")
audio.write_audiofile("wav_output.wav")

                    
with sr.AudioFile("./wav_output.wav") as audio_file:
    audio_data = recognizer.record(audio_file, duration=100)
    transcript = recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio_data=audio_data)
```

I've tried the following

```
from pytube import YouTube
import speech_recognition as sr

video = YouTube(url=link)
audio_stream = video.streams.get_by_itag(140)

buffer = io.BytesIO()
audio_stream.stream_to_buffer(buffer)
                    
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile(buffer) as audio_file:
    audio_data = recognizer.record(audio_file, duration=100)
    transcript = recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio_data=audio_data)
```

I get the following error `audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format` is there a way to convert `buffer` into one of those formats?